# Operation on Regex identified digits in python data frame

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

### I have one data frame with 2 columns 3rd column is output format given below:

DF:

> ```
>        reg     value   o/p**
>     2 for $20    11     20/2
>     4 for $24    12     24/4
>     2 for $30    13     30/2
>  Get $10 Cash    14     14
>     3 for $30    21     30/3
> ```
>
> First, I have to match [\d]+ for [$][\d]+ in reg column and then have
>   to update the value column as 2nd integer of reg divide by the first
>   integer of reg if no match keeps same value.

My code is:

```
df["value"]=df["reg"].map(lambda x: (int(re.findall("[\d]+",x)[1]))/int(re.findall("[\d]+",x)[0]) if(re.search(r"[\d]+ for [$][\d]+" , x)) else x)
```

> The code output is correct for match cases only.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: extract  `2 and 20` from `2 for $20` so that 20/2 can be find. if can be found change value column by this val else let value be as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df["value"]=df.apply(lambda x: (int(re.findall("[\d]+",x["reg"])[1]))/int(re.findall("[\d]+",x["reg"])[0]) if(re.search(r"[\d]+ for [$][\d]+" , x["reg"])) else x["value"], axis=1)
```

**output:**

```
    reg             value
0   2 for $20       10.0
1   4 for $24       6.0
2   2 for $30       15.0
3   Get $10 Cash    14.0
4   3 for $30       10.0
```

you are picking only reg column that's why you were not able to get value